# Active Reports RichTextControl font getting changed when img tag in text

Tags: asp.net, activereports

I've an introduction subreport for my report having only a richtextcontrol and its getting binds with HTML from the DB. Also the text having few img tags in it with its source as a remote image source.

```
<img src='http://www.mydomain.com/photo.jpg'>
```

But the image is loading without any issue. But font of the text immediately after the img tag becomes TimesNewRoman without even thats specified. Our unique font for the report is Arial. But when ever img tag placed in text, text after that getting TimesNewRoman.

I tried with removing all the img tags using regex. After that everything in Arial.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing well.

I am pleased to inform you that the issue reported by you has been fixed in the latest build of [AR7](http://publicfiles.componentone.com/ActiveReports/ActiveReports%207/ActiveReports%20Developer%20v7.3.7973.0.msi) (SP3 release).

Please test the same at your end.

Regards,
Mohita